# Are Lazily fetched objects attached to Hibernate session (Spring Data backed by Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The question is: if I have an entity with a lazily fetched OneToMany collection field inside it and I fetch it from the DB, lets say by its ID, are the elements of the lazy collection attached to the session too? So if I try to query the DB for an entity that is an element of the lazy collection, Hibernate will return the cached instance that and if I try to attach a transient entity with the same ID to that session I will get the EntityExistsException?

Answer (score 1):

> if I have an entity with a lazily fetched OneToMany collection field inside it and I fetch it from the DB, lets say by its ID, are the elements of the lazy collection attached to the session too?

I believe your question is more about, can I load the lazy collection in the different session later.

First thing is, they are attached to the session. So after you close that session it becomes transient and trying to access the collection fields would throw `LazyInitializationException`. Same is true even if you try to access the collection field in a different new open session (without making it managed entity in this session).

So if want to access/populate the lazy collection in another new session, you need to make this entity managed by calling say `merge` method and subsequently you can access the lazy collection in this new session.

> So if I try to query the DB for an entity that is an element of the
>   lazy collection, Hibernate will return the cached instance

If it is in the same session, hibernate would return it from its first level cache if it is already present, else will fire query to DB and place it in the first level cache and used for subsequent queries.

If in a different session, it is a different first level cache and so query is fired to DB. First level cache is session specific and is not shared across sessions.

> if I try to attach a transient entity with the same ID to that session I
>   will get the EntityExistsException?

I presume you are referring to calling the `merge` method on an existing entity that was detached - when you say `attach a transient entity with the same ID` -

- If the entity is not already there in the first level cache, it will load it from the DB, merge it and returns the merged entity
- If the entity is already present, it will merge and returns the merged entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It doesn't make a difference that they're loaded lazily, as soon as the loading is triggered, they'll be managed objects too (and if they're already in the 1st level cache, they'll be fetched from there instead of the database).

Comment: Even if the getter for the lazy collection is never called?

Comment: @user2080472 Then they aren't loaded. Is this some kind of [Zen koan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan)? Obviously something that hasn't been loaded won't be put anywhere.